# Will there exist one set of previewsize greater than screensize in Android?

Tags: android

My mobile's(screen) is 1280X720.
From `parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()`, there does not exist one size that is bigger than 1280X720.
Does anyone know if there is some device that there exist one set of previewsize greater than screensize in Android?
From my point of view, if preview size is bigger than screen size, it is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not usless, you can capture the Preview Images as actual pictures, if you want.

There are preview sizes bigger that screen size, I think almost all phones that have 800x480 resolution and 5MP camera (Galaxy S series) will have a max preview size of 1280x720.

On lower resolution phones (480x320) you can find decent cameras which will provide 800x600 prewview size.

The best use for bigger preview sizes than screen sizes is to provide zoom at a good quality.